# What if some structure occupies 10 bits in a byte addressable memory?

Tags: memory, memory-address, cpu-architecture

Assuming the structure starts at address/index 1000 in a byte addressable memory - how will the system work? Is this byte/word addressable it just for the sake of naming and ease of access? How does the processor acknowledges that the next address has started?

Comment: The compiler would have to emit bit shifts and stuff to re-align it when operating on it. Which is why compilers do not place objects on bit boundaries.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Sorry can you explain it without referring it to compilers (in terms of memory access by processor) - I have edited the question as well! I have no knowledge of bit shifts in memory!

Comment: IIRC most processors cannot load data on a bit offset. You could theoretically create an architecture that can, but there's not much of a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For processors that are byte addressable (which is all processors that I am aware of), the smallest granularity for a data access is a single byte.  Although accesses are typically done at a larger word granularity (usually 4 or 8 bytes).

If you want to load 10 consecutive bits starting at address `0x1000` you would needed to load the first byte from address `0x1000` and the second byte from address `0x1001`.  However, for the second byte you would also need to use some operation to mask off the unwanted bits.

Another thing to note is that the register size in the CPU is usually either 32 or 64 bits.  A 10 bit structure would be difficult to work with and is not something that you are likely to see in practice.

Comment: In a 10 bit structure, 1 byte will be completely and consumed and remaining 2 bits will be consumed from the next byte - so is it possible to save another structure/variable from the 11th bit (or 3rd bit of the 2nd byte)? Secondly, how does a processor know that one byte has ended & other has started?

Comment: To answer your second question, a byte is simply a grouping of 8 bits.  So conceptually byte 0 is bits 0 to 7 in memory, and byte 1 is bits 8 to 15.  To access a field smaller than a byte you need to mask off the bits you not interested in within that byte, keeping only the ones you care about.  So in theory you could have consecutive 10 bit structures, but you would need some logic in your program to keep track of which bits you were interested in.